# Error in Java function call using BlazeDS after recompiling java class in new java version 1.7.0_21

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, blazeds

Can somebody tell me what this flex stack trace means. I am calling a java function from flex using BlazeDS. The class all worked fine, but now I've recompiled the java class using java version 1.7.0_21 and it stopped working and throwing the following fault event.
Please tell me what went wrong.

```
(mx.rpc::Fault)#0
  errorID = 0
  faultCode = "Server.Processing"
  faultDetail = (null)
  faultString = "example/HelloWorld : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class example.HelloWorld)"
  message = "faultCode:Server.Processing faultString:'example/HelloWorld : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class example.HelloWorld)' faultDetail:'null'"
  name = "Error"
  rootCause = (Object)#1
    cause = (null)
    localizedMessage = "example/HelloWorld : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class example.HelloWorld)"
    message = "example/HelloWorld : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class example.HelloWorld)"
```

**HelloWorld.java**

```
package example;
    public class HelloWorld {

    public HelloWorld() {

    }

    public String getHelloWorld() {

    return "Hello Java World!";

    }

    public float addTwoNumbers(float a, float b)
    {
    return a+b;
    }

    }
```

Comment: I'd tag your your question with `Java` rather than `Flex` because this looks like a pure Java issue; from the looks of it, some kind of incompatibility issue. Try to get a hold of the original Java exception rather than the message passed to the Flex front: it'll give you more information.

Comment: I'd not tagged as `Java`, as the code is working fine if I run it on command prompt. May be the problem is with Flex-Java interfacing or with BlazeDS. Again, there is no problem with the code as it is working fine if I compile it using Java 6(or jdk 1.6 precisely), the error occurs when I compile it in Java 7.

Comment: I'd rather think it's an incompatibility between the compiled code and the server you run it on. For instance if you run your Java 7 compiled code on Tomcat 6 (which I think isn't compatible with Java 7) you might get something like this. I'm no Java expert, but I'm a Flex expert and I can tell you this: you're barking up the wrong tree

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am using Tomcat 6. Can u tell me which version would be compatible with Java 7